# Grails how to sort list by children max date using criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails (version 3.1.5) and trying to sort a list by the max date of a children class

**Domain:**

```
class Entity {
    static hasMany = [childrens: Children]
}

class Children {
    Date date
}
```

**Something like this in SQL:**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    entity
INNER JOIN 
    children c1 ON c1.entity_id = entity.id
WHERE 
    c1.date = 
        (SELECT MAX(c2.date) FROM children c2 WHERE c2.entity_id = c1.entity_id) 
ORDER BY 
    c1.date DESC
```

Does anyone know how to do this using criteria?

**EDIT:**

I was able to execute the right query with the code below but I couldn't transform the result in a list of Entities (because of the projections):

```
Entity.createCriteria().list(params) {
    childrens {
        projections {
            groupProperty 'entity'
            max 'date', 'maxDate'
        }
    }
    order 'maxDate', 'desc'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to solve this kind of issues is to add some redundnancy:

```
class Entity {
    Date maxChildrenDate

    def beforeInsert() {
      maxChildrenDate = childrens.*date.max()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
      beforeInsert()
    }

    static hasMany = [childrens: Children]
}
```

Then the querying is straight-forward:

```
def list = Entity.list( sort:'maxChildrenDate', order:'asc' )
```

To set/update the `maxChildrenDate` you might want to use interceptors shown above.

Comment: Ok, but that's not the question. I want to know how create the query with criteria

Comment: My answer provides a solution to your problem, not to the straight-forward way you are trying to solve it. The way you have it will result in a low query performance over time